# python 2to3: How to selectively enable fixers and only do one or two of them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3

I am using 2to3 to update some python2 code. Unfortunately there is some fixers I do not like:

- There are some fixers I do trust (like the print fixer).
- So I would like to only run one the fixers I trust.

For Python `2to3`, how do you disable all fixers and only do one or two fixers? For example if you just want to run `print` fixer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to do:

```
2to3 --fix print your_file.py
```

- I misread the documentation.
- When you provide no `--fix`, then all fixers are enabled.
- If you provide one or more `--fix` then only those fixers you specify are processed.
- When you provide `--nofix` and no `--fix`, then all fixers are enabled and only the fixers you specify with `--nofix` are disabled.